# Como utilizar varias llamadas a random.sample y evitar llamar a los mismo elementos de una lista

Tags: python

tengo una lista con 10 elementos (1 a 10) y necesito ir extrayéndolo en 5 listas diferentes pero en cada llamada la cantidad a extraer son aleatorios pueden ser 1 ,2 o 3.

Hasta ahí no tengo problemas el tema es que necesito ir eliminando los que ya me devolvió para que no sean devueltos otra vez en una próxima llamada.

Como puedo hacerlo?

```
dec1=list(range(1,11))

tmp1=random.sample(dec1, 2) 
tmp2=random.sample(dec1, 3) 
tmp3=random.sample(dec1, 1) 
tmp4=random.sample(dec1, 2)
tmp5=random.sample(dec1, 2)
```

Porque del modo que está me devuelve valores duplicados de la lista de este modo

```
print(tmp1,tmp2,tmp3,tmp4,tmp5)
[6, 7] [8, 6, 2] [7] [1, 5] [8, 5]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes obtener una versión ordenada aleatoriamente de la lista usando sample, e ir extrayendo partes de un largo aleatorio (en este caso de 1 a 3).

###### Código

```
import random

dec1 = range(1, 11)

muestra = random.sample(dec1, len(dec1))

current_position = 0
listas = []

for _ in range(5):
    new_position = current_position + random.randint(1, 3)
    listas.append(muestra[current_position:new_position])
    current_position = new_position

print(muestra)
print()

for lista in listas:
    print(lista)
```

###### Produce

```
[5, 6, 4, 10, 7, 3, 1, 8, 9, 2]

[5]
[6, 4]
[10, 7]
[3, 1]
[8, 9]
```

**Nota**: Por una cuestión lógica, si, por ejemplo, al crear la lista 3, extrajiste ya 9 elementos, la lista 4 tendrá 1 solo (pues solo queda un elemento a extraer) y la lista 5 saldrá vacía.

Comment: Uff que bueno!! ya entiendo tu código! lo único que yo lo simplifique para que sea mas entendible. Veré si lo puedo adaptar a esta estructura que planteas. Tu y comento luego. No quería poner todo el code para simplificar.

Comment: Genial amigo!! me salvaste una vez mas como me gastaría tenerte en mi equipo!

Comment: Me alegro de haberte ayudado c: Cualquier cosa que necesites y no sea bien recibido aquí puedes hablarme en [el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol). Recuerda mencionarme con @, que te parece?

Comment: ok! luego lo reviso. Nunca use el chat!

Answer (score 1):

Muchas gracias a Dante por responder. No encontré otra forma para solucionar el problema jajaja. Me quebré la cabeza buscando otra forma. Ya después mi desesperación me llevo a basarme en su respuesta. Cabe decir que soy un novato (14 días de python) y mi teacher me recomendó buscar preguntas en stackoverflow y responderlas para hacerme más fuerte :P.

**Mi código basado en el de Dante:**

```
import random
a = [*range(0,11)]
random.shuffle(a)
b = []
posición = 0

for x in range(5): 
    uno_tres = random.randint(1,3) + posición
    print(a[posición:uno_tres])
    posición += uno_tres
```

**Produce:**

```
[4, 0]
[7, 10]
[2, 1, 5]
[6, 3, 9]
[8]
```

Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias @Jorge por tu aporte también es valido.